# jQuery .each to get .attr of children

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following div `<div id="selected"></div>`. I add elements `<div class="item" id="someID">blah</div>` to the `#selected`. At some point, I run the following:

```
var ids = [];
$('#selected').each(function(){
    ids.push( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

but I get nothing. The only command that works there is `$(this).html()`. Nothing else works. Why is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
var ids = [];
$('#selected div').each(function(){ //descendent selector added
    ids.push( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Your code isn't working because $('#selected') is just returning you one node, since there is only one node with that id(as should be, id's are supposed to be unique)

Answer (score 1):

ID is Unique so don't use `.each()` with  it

you want to get children of element with id `selected` so use `$('#selected').children()`

Try [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var ids = $('#selected').children().map(function(){
    return  this.id;
}).get();
```

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJcv5/)

Comment: all of my ids are unique. This doesn't work at all. So even if i type $(this).attr('class'), it still doesn't return anything. Like i said, I can only use $(this).html(), which seems to work just fine ...